# Add Variable to Class Name

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop, wpbakery

I am currently developing an element for WPBakery in Wordpress.

Because I want to nest the elements into each other I have to append a unique ID to the class of the element. 
The Variable $uniqueID shoud be appended to the Class "WPBakeryShortCode_vc_BootstrapCol"

But I can't do that in this way:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
        class WPBakeryShortCode_vc_BootstrapCol . $uniqueID extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a hint on how to do this?

If I write the id behind it myself it works. Like this:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
        class WPBakeryShortCode_vc_BootstrapCol9346f805fc69ff0bb9f83511df30b1a9 extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval()`

```
if ( class_exists( 'WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
    eval("class WPBakeryShortCode_vc_BootstrapCol" . (int)$uniqueID . " extends WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {}");
}
```

Although this seems strange to me. Make sure you have a good reason to do that.

Comment: Yes! That was i was looking for! Thanks!
Now I have another problem. I can't access "$this->uniqueID" outside the class. I have updated the question and inserted all the code.

I want to do this because the shortcodes of every instance has to be different, to nest them to each other. And the "base" has to be the same as the shortcode, and the Class name has to be the same as the base. maybe I'm thinking the wrong way. But it seems so logical to me.

Comment: I suggest you to create a different question here in stackoverflow with your issue. It will be easier to help you without mixing things. If this answer worked for you, you can mark as accepted to help others with the same issue.